# ExpandableListAdapter methods are not working properly in my case. Any alternate to ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using an `ExpandableListAdapter` for the first time. I have some textviews in the groupView and some buttons in childView. I've used the following code from the internet and tried to convert it according to my preference. But there is a problem in the `getGroupCount()` method. I know in my code `_listDataHeader` and `_listDataChild` are null, but what should I use instead? Here are the pictures of my header view

[image: header View layout]

```
  and Child View layout
```

[image: child view layout].

On the click of header this child View should be shown on screen.. Am i using the correct android View for this design? Please help

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Activity context;
ArrayList<String> s_date,c_number,d_ration,s_time,download_path,a_number,a_name;
String id[];
String mUrl;

private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> start_date, ArrayList<String> caller_number, ArrayList<String> duration,ArrayList<String> start_time, ArrayList<String> download_path, ArrayList<String> agent_number, ArrayList<String> agent_name) {
    this.context=context;
    this.s_date=start_date;
    this.c_number=caller_number;
    this.d_ration=duration;
    this.s_time=start_time;
    this.download_path=download_path;
    this.a_number=agent_number;
    this.a_name=agent_name;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    Button play_button=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("play child is",childText);

        }
    });

    Button download_button=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.download);
    download_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("download child is",childText);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.s_date.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView start_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start_date);
    start_date.setText(s_date.get(groupPosition));
    TextView caller_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caller_number);
    caller_number.setText(c_number.get(groupPosition));
    TextView duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    duration.setText(d_ration.get(groupPosition));
    TextView start_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
    start_time.setText(s_time.get(groupPosition));
    TextView agent_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agent_name);
    agent_name.setText(a_name.get(groupPosition));
    TextView agent_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agent_number);
    agent_number.setText(a_number.get(groupPosition));
   // start_date.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
   // start_date.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}


@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
 }
```

and this is how i'm setting the adpater

```
     ExpandableListAdapter a=new ExpandableListAdapter(MainScreen.this,start_date,caller_number,duration,start_time,download_path,agent_number,agent_name);
    data_list.setAdapter(a);
```

Comment: where are you setting the header and child items?

Comment: header must be single item, the child view may or many not be more than one item. you have to use the header id to your child items key. thats all

Comment: I have one Layout for headers and an another layout for child @Ahamed and in this code i know that _listDataHeader and _listDataChild are null but what should i set instead of them, according to my code?

Comment: You have to clear unwanted argument passing in constructor. use this url for expandablelistview. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: @Ahamed i have used the code from same url and converted it according to my preference.. let me attach the pictures about what am i trying to achieve

Comment: no need. i got you already, expandablelistview is parent and child relation.i wll post the _listDataHeader and _listDataChild code below.

Comment: @Ahamed should i use ExpandableListView for the design am i tagetting to?

Comment: @RBoughan I think shouldn't it done with visible and gone method with normal ListView? Why you are in need of expandable listview?

Comment: @R Boughan expandablelistview is easiest one. you need to use expandablelistview or recyclerview. that is depends upon you. you can use expandablelistview for your scenario .

Comment: Thank you so much @Ahamed for your help. But i have used visible and gone method as suggested by Pratik Dasa and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by @PratikDasa I have used Custom ListView and in that i have used Visible gone method. Below is the solution.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sub_layout"
    android:background="#FFC7FFFE"
    android:visibility="gone">
```

I have set all the contents(Buttons in my case) under this sub_layout and set layout visibilty as gone.
And then on the click of any of the list item(Headers), I have shown the sub_layout that i have set as gone.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, g, false);

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // Toast.makeText(context,"i'm Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            RelativeLayout sub_list=(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);
            sub_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Now it works like an ExpandableListView.